# Confidence Intervals for nominal scale

Tags: confidence-interval, categorical-data

I have nominal variable X with 4 categories: a, b, c, d.
After data collection I have got:
a - 50%,
b - 25%,
c - 10%,
d - 15%.
Now I would like to calculate confidece intervals for a, b, c and d.
I know that it is easy to do for dummy variables, but I have more categories, than two.
Should I consider a, b, c and d as dummy variable and calculate CI for proportion or there is more appropriate way?

Comment: Do you need a confidence *region* or individual confidence intervals?  If it's the latter, then you have four separate calculations each of which involves just two categories: a and non-a; b and non-b; and so on.

Comment: I thought only about CI for each category. But you mentioned confidence region. And I just realised - I have no idea how to use it for nominal data.